# Angular Bootstrap within Single Page Application

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

We have a parent site that provides the real estate for our applications to be added. The flow is described as below

1. Parent site has a menu.
2. One of the "links" on the menu points to our
   application
3. When you click on it, the parent site internally parses
   the response from our application (including html and javascript)
   and loads it within a container. Sort of a portlet. This parsing is problematic, because once the javascript is loaded, it remains in the head tag.
4. Thereafter, we can use our code to control the application in a SPI manner.

Problem arises, when the user clicks on the menu again, because steps 1-4 get repeated. Thus we end up reloading javascript, which fails spectacularly. Some of the problems include

1. Angular is reloaded.
2. Modules get reloaded.
3. If I defer the loading of Angular conditionally via document.write, then I have to ensure that angular is loaded before the modules are defined.
4. If I manually bootstrap the application, then I cannot bootstrap it again and I need flags to maintain.
5. I was able to write a script to ensure that everything is loaded only once, but now the problem is that the DOM does not get "processed" once the user clicks the link again. It is as if the entire DOM content has refreshed with the angular tags and directives, and the javascript is already loaded, but it does not "process" this new DOM content.

What can I do to ensure that newly added DOM via a third party plugin/script/code is recognized by existing angular code?

Comment: A plunker is worth a thousand words. But most likely you need to `$compile` the element that contains refreshed content.

Comment: That's essentially my entire application. The main body along with the associated tags is what I'm talking about here. Not specifically DOM fragment. Is it possible to manually compile the entire page?

Comment: I guess your application contains the actual code, while the question certainly does not. There's no reason to compile the entire page because only `ng-app` element needs to be compiled (if it is `body` then do $compile on it). Yes, it is possible, and yes, it smells bad, there may be ways to improve the app and make it smell good, but you will hardly get a quality answer without showing the code.

Comment: @estus, the application code is irrelevant, imo. Nevertheless, I understand your point.